# Memory and performance comparison of injected vs singleton services in Angular 7

Tags: angular

I would like to understand the memory and performance implications of singleton vs injected services in Angular 7.

For example, let's say that I have a list of components on a page and each one is injected the same service (i.e. it's listed in the component providers). Does this mean that if I have e.g. 50 components, I will need 50 times the memory requirements for the injected service, vs a singleton service that is common to all?

Are there any other performance implications to consider?

Comment: It is better to quote specifics from the documentation in your questions, then to ask questions which appear to indicate that you didn't read the documentation. https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection

Comment: It is better to point to or quote the specific part in a long documentation page that answers the question. In this case, I assume it's https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#injector-hierarchy-and-service-instances but it still doesn't answer my question clearly.

Comment: If the instance is especially created for your component, then you have 50 instances instead of one. But I'm really not sure about the design of such a thing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to understand the memory and performance implications of singleton vs injected services in Angular 7.

Dependencies in Angular are handled via providers. There are many types of providers such as constant values, factories, classes etc.. etc..

A *service* refers to an injectable class that has been instantiated. When it is *instantiated* depends upon *when* it is *provided*. The most common place to declare a provider is in the declaration of a *module*. So we refer to this as the *scope* of the provider.

A provider by default is a *single* value resolver, but it's possible to configure a provider as *multiple*. For simplicity sacks let's assume providers are singletons within a scope.

A *scope* can have a *parent* and *children*. When a *provider* is declared it is provided in the *current* scope. Modules tend to be very high up on the injector tree with the *root* at the top.

When a component is created we can think of that as a new scope. With the bootstrap component at the top of the component tree, but given that you can use a factory to create a new component means you shouldn't assume everything is part of the same tree.

Yeah it can get complicated.

> For example, let's say that I have a list of components on a page and each one is injected the same service (i.e. it's listed in the component providers).

Let's assume this service is named `FooBarService`. I can explain the many different things that can happen based upon how you've configured the dependency injector.

1. The injector will throw an error that `FooBarService` is an unknown dependency.
2. The root module has provided `FooBarService` and this component and all other components will receive the same instance.
3. The lazy loaded module has provided `FooBarService` and this component will receive an instance, but components outside the lazy module will throw an error of unknown dependency.
4. The parent component has provided `FooBarService` and all its children components will receive an instance.
5. Each component has provided `FooBarService` and each component receives a new instance.

Since you've stated "it's listed in the component providers" then option #5 would apply.

See this reference: https://angular.io/guide/providers#providing-services-in-modules-vs-components

> Does this mean that if I have e.g. 50 components, I will need 50 times the memory requirements for the injected service, vs a singleton service that is common to all?

Yes, if you have declared the provider in the scope of a component and not the scope of a module. There will be one instance per component that has declared it, but that instanced is shared for the children of that component.

> Are there any other performance implications to consider?

Yes, it requires more memory and time to create 50 components if the injector has to create new instances. Will it have a negative impact on your software? As with any decision it depends upon why you are doing it. If it is to resolve a dependency problem, then it might be the only way to do it. If you can use a shared singleton service instead, then I would wonder why you weren't doing that.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer, this is more like what I was looking for. I will have to go through it more carefully later, but unless someone comes up with a better explanation I will accept it. And yes, I was talking about option #5. If I got it right, your answer, combined with the article by Netanel Basal mentioned in another answer, implies that if a service is to be used by more than one components, and possibly a lot, then it should be a singleton.

Comment: @AsGoodAsItGets the only times I've used providers at the component level are for  reactive forms, and injecting configuration options. For example; set the background color of tooltips in child components to a different color. My point is to reserve it for special cases where there isn't another way.

Answer (score 1):

> Does this mean that if I have e.g. 50 components, I will need 50 times
>   the memory requirements for the injected service, vs a singleton
>   service that is common to all?

This will only happen if each component has a different module and:

- each module provide the service;
- or the service is provided in one module and this module is imported in each component module;

If any component share a module whose provide the service, it will be singleton around these components.

I've reading a very good article from **Netanel Basal** - [*"Angular Services do NOT have to be Singleton*"](https://netbasal.com/angular-services-do-not-have-to-be-singletons-ffa879e62082)

Where he says about singleton services:

`The sole purpose of the service is to share data between child’s components and to provide a couple of helper’s methods.`

If you have a singleton service, it will be only one instance but in the whole application lifecycle (even when you are not using it), otherwise, if you have non singleton services instances, it will be consuming much more memory and each service intance will be destroyed only when all component of its module was destroyed.

I would say that you could try to control the trade-off of these benefits in your application.

Other non singleton benefit is:

We can even implement `ngOnInit`and `ngOnDestroy` lifecycle, you can check it [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-service-lifecycle?file=app%2Fhello%2Fhello.module.ts).

Comment: I've read the same article while googling for an answer, but it still wasn't clear to me.